# Java Web Start is not working

Tags: java, jdbc, java-web-start

I have been working on a Java project. It is now over but Java Web start is not working. I compile the program and put dist files in my Tomcat Server. I want clients to download my program and use as a desktop application.

I can run the program inside Netbeans IDE just fine, however when I try it using `.jnlp` file it is giving errors. Until a while ago I managed to run the program using jnlp, somehow it is giving below errors. I can still run the program with executable jar but I desperately need to use Java Web Start.

```
 `Exception in thread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.setContextClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:38)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:298)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dbo.dealSave.user(dealSave.java:364)
    at TradeX.uyegiris.jButton1ActionPerformed(uyegiris.java:177)
    at TradeX.uyegiris.access$100(uyegiris.java:20)
    at TradeX.uyegiris$2.actionPerformed(uyegiris.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JavaWebStartSecurity.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:70)
    ... 43 more
`
```

Below is the jnlp file. Sorry it is too long. I can provide additional information.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://192.168.0.162:9999/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Unit Elektrik Trader Team</title>
        <vendor>seckin.celik</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>Versiyon 1</description>
        <description kind="short">Unit Elektrik Trader Team</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="Trade.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/jxl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/cglib-2.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jta-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-tools-3.6.0.CR1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/c3p0-0.9.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/oscache-2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/cglib-2.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jta-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-tools-3.6.0.CR1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/c3p0-0.9.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/oscache-2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxb-impl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxb-xjc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/FastInfoset.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/gmbal-api-only.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ha-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.mail_1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxws-rt.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxws-tools.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/management-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mimepull.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/policy.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/saaj-impl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/stax-ex.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/stax2-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/streambuffer.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/woodstox-core-asl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxws-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jsr181-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.annotation.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/saaj-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/activation.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxb-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jsr173_1.0_api.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="TradeX.uyegiris">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>`
```

Answer (score 2):

As the Error points out, you have problems with permission.
(Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read"))
Further, you are missing the **security**-Tag in your JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8585/" href="Test.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Test</title>
        <vendor>Test</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8585/" />
        <description>Test</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/> <!-- SEE HERE FOR EXAMPLE --!>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="TestJnlp.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.test.TestJnlp" />
</jnlp>
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT**:
As of Java 7u51, there are some changes in security!
you may check following:
https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias

Persmission-Info also needs to be added to **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**!

Comment: I tried adding security tags. It is strange even after adding tags I am getting Exception in thread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")

Comment: Could you post your *updated* JNLP? Because you wrote "i tried adding security tags". But there is only **one** tag (with closing tag)

Answer (score 0):

By default a java web start application runs in a sandbox (like an Applet). The error seems to come from a missing permission to read the `file.encoding` system property. You need to define in your jnlp the level of permission that your application needs. Adding the following element should fix your permission problem.

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```